# Why is my logo being cached? (Disabling cache for a specific block tpl.php file)

Tags: theming, 8, caching

I have this in my template:

```
<img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

I wrote a preprocess function to override site_logo:

```
function theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) 
{
    if (siteMode() == 1) 
    {
        $variables['site_logo'] = '/_logo1.png';
    }
    else {
        $variables['site_logo'] = '/_logoOther.png';
    }
}
```

However, if I clear cache when siteMode == 1, it shows logo1.png. But then if site_mode changes to 2, it doesn't show logoOther unless I again clear the cache. This leads me to believe it caches the resulting HTML. Which makes sense, I guess, but then how would I be able to do something like the above?

I also tried adding my own Twig Extension and then editing block--system-branding-block.html.twig like this:

```
{% if get_site_mode() == 1 %}
    <img src="/_logo1.png" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" /> 
{% endif %}
{% if get_site_mode() != 1 %}
    <img src="/_logoOther.png" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" /> 
{% endif %}
```

This also has the same result. It always shows the one until I clear cache.

Can someone please steer me in the right direction. What should I be using to accomplish what I want? which is to simply switch the logo based on the current mode. Where current mode is determined by a global function called "getSiteMode()".

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

I tried "set", which worked in html.tpl.php, but not in this template file i am currently working on. This leads me to believe the issue is that I need to disable caching for a specific template?

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What is inside getSiteMode()?

Comment: Just to understand, what code is `siteMode()` using?